# Speeding up the saving excel process while using Styleframe

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlsxwriter, styleframe

I am using `StyleFrame`'s `to_excel`  function to save the dataframe `df` in `.xlsx` file. Below is my code which works fine:

```
 import pandas as pd
 from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, Styler

 bgStyle = Styler(bg_color='yellow')
 sf = StyleFrame(df)
 sf.apply_style_by_indexes([1,2], styler_obj=bgStyle, overwrite_default_style=False)

 sf.to_excel('output.xlsx').save()
```

Since my dataframe is big , so to speed up the writing and saving process , I want to use `engine='xlsxwriter'` but  `StyleFrame`'s `to_excel` function doesnt have `engine` as a parameter.

So how can I speed up the process of writing and saving df into .xlsx while using Styleframe for styling?

Comment: How big is your dataframe? styleframe is indeed not the fastest, since it needs to iterate over every single cell in order to apply the correct style. `engine` is not a parameter since only openpyxl is supported.

Comment: my dataframe can have upto 100,000 rows and 10 columns.

Comment: Do you have any plan to add engine has parameter in near future?

Comment: Not at the moment, but I'm always open to pull requests on github ;)

Comment: Are any updates available?